# How to use single piece of middleware with more than one express router?

Tags: node.js, express, authorization

I am working on a university project and we have decided to go for MEAN technology stack. To be honest I am a beginner with `NodeJS` and `express`, more precisely this is the first time I do sth with it. 
I've found that is preferable to use `express.Router` rather than putting all routes to express instance e.g. `app.post('path', function(req, res) { ... })`

So this is what I have

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

function authorizationMiddleware(req, res, next) {
...
}

// handles login, doesn't meed autorizationMiddleware
var authRouter = express.Router();
authRouter.route('/login')
    .post(function (req, res) {
    ...
    });

// handles fetching of a single, all person(s), fetching of transactions for a person
var personRouter = require('./routes/personRoutes')(Person, Transaction, autorizationMiddleware);
//handles adding of a new transaction e.g. POST /api/transactions where params such as sender, recipient and amount are passed in body
var transactionRouther = require('./routes/transactionRoutes')(Person, Transaction, autorizationMiddleware);

app.use('/api', authRouter);
app.use('/api/persons', personRouter);
app.use('/api/transactions', transactionRoutes);

app.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('Listening on port: ' + 8080);
});
```

As you can see I have three routers (not even sure if I have gonne too far with them), `authRouter` is handling login only and I have also decided to separate persons logic from transactions logic too. (maybe I could have handled creation of new transaction in a way like `/api/persons/:personId/transactions` but I rather liked the idea of sending all required params in body).

I would like to ask if you agree with the solution I tried. As you can see I am passing `authrizationMiddleware` function (handles verification of JWT token) function to router modules and using it there. 
Is there maybe a better way to use the same middleware with of multiple routers or is this a legit way?

Thx in advance
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you use 3 `Router`s. The "common" way to go (or at least the way I go) is to put all the routes in the same place, except when the path is very different or the purpose is different (for example I separate the error routes from the others).

For example, let's say I need to build a rest api for an app, I would probably have paths like:

```
/users/:userid
/users/:userid/comments/:commentid
/locations
...
```

All these routes can go in the same `Router` and if you want, you can apply specific authentication/authorization middlewares to them:

```
router.get("/users/:userid", 
        doAuthentication, authorizeOnUserId, 
        userController.getUserById);

router.get("/locations", 
        doAuthentication, authorizeLocations, 
        locationController.getAllLocations);
```

The middlewares are called in sequence and the request is passed on to the next middleware only if there are no errors (unauthenticaed/ unhauthorized).
Then you can simply import your routes like this:

```
app.use('/api', router);
```

Using this technique allows you to have a fine grain control over your routes.
Hope this helps.